# django-import-export specify id in order from ‘1’

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

When I import data from excel, I find the default id is random：

```
ID   NAME
5    A
9    B
```

I want it to look like the below example when I import data "NAME: A, NAME: B" from excel:

```
ID   NAME
1    A
2    B
```

How can I do this?

```
class assets_resource(resources.ModelResource):

class Meta:
    model = assets
    skip_unchanged = True   
    report_skipped = False

@admin.register(assets)
class data_import(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'sn']
    search_fields = ['id', 'sn']
    ordering = ['id', 'sn']
    resource_class = assets_resource
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Comment: that may be because you have deleted some of the rows after creating them and data with those id no more exist in database.

Comment: I just used the django-import-export，the ID is django default set. @John Gordon.

Comment: But the database is new，nothing I have deleted.